# Returning a value from Task<IActionResult>

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have this OnGet method that runs in a razorpage when I click the approve button.

As you can see below the actual code that runs is in a utility class and as I do not want to break the threading procedure the utility class method also returns the Task

When the execution returns I write the "message" to the browser. My problem is that it is not the Id I want to display for the user. it is another column in sql which is available in the utility class.

So my question here is how can change my call to return a value from the Utility class method?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetApproveAsync(int id) {

        try {
            await Utils.ApproveOrder(Request, HttpContext, _context1, _context2, _cache, id);
            Message += "Order #" + id + " Approved\n";
            return Redirect("~/Orders/Orders");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Message += e.StackTrace.ToString();
            return Redirect("~/Orders/Orders");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `Utils.ApproveOrder` to return `Task<Utility>` and update model code

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetApproveAsync(int id) {
    try {
        Utility util = await Utils.ApproveOrder(Request, HttpContext, _context1, _context2, _cache, id);
        //use util
        //..
}
```